# How can I incorporate .addClass jQuery code into a Ruby on Rails callback method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a to do list web app that creates task items with varying priority levels (Low,Medium,High). What I'd like to do is to have the corresponding CSS class added to the element depending on the Priority.

1. Low = Green
2. Medium = Orange
3. High = Red

This is what I have for my index.html.erb. (I don't know if this is relevant but I made my task logic into a partial):

```
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= task.name %></td>
  <td><%= task.description %></td>
  <td><%= task.start %></td>
  <td><%= task.finish %></td>
  <td><%= task.importance %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_task_path(task) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Remove', task_path(task), method: :delete, 
      data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you would like to Delete? Did you complete the  
      task?' } %></td>
</tr> 
<% end %>
```

I have a priority.js.erb file that contains the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if (<% @task.importance == "Low" %>) {
    $("td").addClass("green");
  } 
  else if(<% @task.importance == "Medium" %>) {
    $("td").addClass("orange");
  } 
  else {
    $("td").addClass("red");
  }
});
```

The error message that I receive is:

```
ndefined method `importance' for nil:NilClass
```

Am I on the right track here? I originally thought of having an after_create: , after_update: callback in my controller but then I realized that I don't think I can use jQuery code in a .rb file.

I was thinking something like this:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create do |task|
    some javascript code to change the color
  end
end
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Watch out, there are some risky behavior right here. Adding some javascript in an 'after_create' is not possible since it breaks MVC rules. Javascript belongs to the view layer. You shouldn't have some model method having a direct impact on your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScripts are requested during a completely separate request/response cycle from the main HTML of your page. There will not be an `@task` variable, as no controller is involved in serving up your assets.

You need to move your code into the body of your page, or at least serve up the value of `@task.importance` during the main request when your controller's action is actually invoked and `@task` is defined.

Comment: Thanks for the response meagar. I'll try moving it onto the body for starters. For your second option, would I need to use AJAX for something like that or maybe a call back method after_create: etc.

Comment: No, you'd put something like `window.task = <%= @task.toJSON() %>` in your view, and then access `window.task` inside priority.js